# List con Type dinámico para castear JSON arrays

Tags: java, android, json, reflection

Estoy trabajando con un conjunto de servicios web. Como ya es normal, estos servicios trabajan con JSON y cada uno siempre responde con un array de una entidad específica (`Persona, Animal, etc.`)

Hasta allí todo normal, no tengo problemas con los servicios; hacen lo que tienen que hacer.

En mi Android App quiero (como sé que siempre son arrays) realizar el cast de estos `arrays` en formato `JSON` a `List<?>`, en donde `?` debe ser la clase que corresponde al `JSON` para realizar el cast.

Para ello tengo lo siguiente y el motivo de mi pregunta:

Primero, hice un `xml` con los nombres completos de las clases (`package + nombre de clase`)

```
<item>com.company.package.Person</item>
<item>com.company.package.Animal</item>
<item>com.company.package.Thing</item>
// etc
```

Segundo, el orden de llamado a los servicios web corresponde con el orden de las clases en el anterior array, entonces sabiendo eso; puedo (pensé que podía) "castear" el `JSON array` con un `Type` de tipo `List<?>` así:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Person>() {}.getType();
List<Person> array = gson.fromJson(jsonArrayString, type);
```

Colocando directamente el tipo `Person`, pues claro que funciona, pero mi idea es hacerlo un poco más dinámico (en realidad quiero ahorrarme el escribir muchas lineas con lo mismo), para ello se carga el `xml` con los nombres de las clases en un `String array`

```
String[] entities = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.classNames);
```

Luego con el `String` con el nombre completo de la clase, obtener el `Class`

```
Class<?> object = Class.forName(entities[y]); 
// supongamos que para la posicion y tiene "com.company.Person"
```

Hasta allí todo bien, pero ahora no encuentro manera de colocar este `object` en el `Type` de `TypeToken` y en el `Type` del `List`

La pregunta es: ¿es posible realizar esto? yo supongo que sí, pero quizá tengo un mal enfoque o me falta algo por hacer.

Comment: No manejo la librería gson pero me parece que podrías utilizar [`TypeToken#get`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html#get%28java.lang.reflect.Type%29) y pasar como argumento la variable `Class<?> object`.

Comment: Como estas bajando la informacion? Usas Asynctask o Retrofit, o algo diferente?

Comment: Bueno, en este punto del proceso es irrelevante pero la información se descarga en un AsyncTask. Al momento del `cast` ya se han ejecutado todas las llamadas a servicios.

Comment: Me da algo de curiosidad porque deseas realizar todo esto y no solo convertir la respuesta de los objetos .json a un List<> ???

Comment: Porque si solo hago lo que usted comenta sucede esto: `Attempted to deserialize a java.lang.Class. Forgot to register a type adapter?` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Pude lograrlo con algo de ayuda de StackOverflow (inglés) y añadiendo algo de mi investigación.

El truco está en implementar la interface `java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType` (sugerido por el portal en inglés) de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

public class ParameterizedTypeList implements ParameterizedType {
    private final Class<?> clazz;

    public ParameterizedTypeList(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[] { clazz };
    }

    @Override
    public Type getRawType() {
        return List.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Paso el `class` de mi objeto por constructor como es lo normal, pero el `rawType` es de tipo `List` ya que es específicamente lo que estoy manipulando, arreglos de objetos. Con esta implementación; en mi proceso de "casting masivo" ahora puedo hacer lo siguiente:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(entities[y]);
Type type = new ParameterizedTypeList(clazz.newInstance().getClass());
List<? extends Object> array = gson.fromJson(datos.get(y).toString(), type);
```

Se carga un objeto `Class` de acuerdo al nombre de la clase en el arreglo y se crea una instancia del mismo para obtener su `Type` (`clazz.newInstance().getClass()`) y como en tiempo de compilación no puedo saber de qué tipo será el objeto albergado en la lista, el super padre debe ser Object `List<? extends Object>`

Espero le ayude a alguien, el otro post puede ser consultado [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286991/java-dynamic-list-type-to-cast-json-array/36292903?noredirect=1#comment60304403_36292903).